# Magento 1.9 sql injection on category/product page

Tags: php, sql, magento-1.9, sql-injection, zend-form

We are using Magento 1.9.0.1 version. We scan the website and found some issue related to the SQL injection on the category/product page. Any once can help to resolve SQL injection on category/product page.

Comment: Update Magento to the latest version basically; 1.9.3.9

Comment: sure, if you are ready to pay for the task